# Why is TIFFRepresentation bigger than the actual image file?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsimage, nsimagerep

Here's the code I use:

```
NSImage *image = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] imageForResource:@"test.jpg"];
NSData *originalData = [image TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression:NSTIFFCompressionJPEG factor:1.];
```

The `originalData.length` gives me 1802224 bytes (1.7MB). While the image size on the disk is 457KB. Why does `TIFFRepresentation` get larger and which representation I should use in order to get original image (i want to transfer image over the network)?

Answer (score 5):

TIFF is much bigger than JPEG. No surprise there.

However, the answer to your actual question is: don't use *any* "representation". You *have* the data (namely, the file itself); send it! Don't turn the image file into an NSImage; grab it as an NSData.

Comment: hm. so basically, in scenarios where user drags and drops an image, i'll just need to carry additional reference to a file dropped, alongside the image (which is used in UI).

Comment: You _could_ make a JPEG representation of the image, but that seems rather wasteful when the file on disk _is_ a JPEG.